# Fixed top bar moves to top of page when opening off canvas mmenu

Tags: jquery, mmenu

Is there a way to keep the fixed top bar in place when the off-canvas mmenu opens?

When the page has been scrolled, The fixed top bar disappears when the off canvas menu opens.

fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/sojourner7/yxcLhp6g/1/

```js
   $(function() {
    $('nav#menu').mmenu({
        "offCanvas": {
            "position": "left"
        }
    });
});
```

```css
html, body
{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
body
{
 background-color: #fff;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 22px;
 color: #666;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
body *
{
 text-shadow: none;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{
 line-height: 1;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
}
h1, h2, h3
{
 font-size: 18px;
}
h4, h5, h6
{
 font-size: 16px;
}
p
{
 margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
a, a:link, a:active, a:visited, a:hover
{
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

nav:not(.mm-menu)
{
 display: none;
}

.header,
.content,
.footer
{
 text-align: center;
}
.header,
.footer
{
 background: #777;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #fff;
 line-height: 40px;


 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box; 
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
 padding: 0 50px;
}
.header.fixed
{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
.footer.fixed
{
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}
.header a
{
 background: center center no-repeat transparent;
 background-image: url( data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABkAAAAZCAYAAADE6YVjAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAADhJREFUeNpi/P//PwOtARMDHQBdLGFBYtMq3BiHT3DRPU4YR4NrNAmPJuHRJDyahEeT8Ii3BCDAAF0WBj5Er5idAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC );

 display: block;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 10px;
}
.menutrigger a
{
 background: center center no-repeat transparent;
 background-image: url( data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABkAAAAZCAYAAADE6YVjAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAADhJREFUeNpi/P//PwOtARMDHQBdLGFBYtMq3BiHT3DRPU4YR4NrNAmPJuHRJDyahEeT8Ii3BCDAAF0WBj5Er5idAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC );

 display: block;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 background-color:#ccc;
}
.content
{
 padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.geneva-college.com/geneva-responsive/mmenu-geneva/src/js/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.geneva-college.com/geneva-responsive/mmenu-geneva/src/css/jquery.mmenu.all.css" />


<div id="page">
    <div class="header fixed"> <a href="#menu"></a>
Demo</div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
        <p>In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.</p>
        <p>Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
        <p>In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.</p>
        <p>Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>
        <br />
    </div>
    <nav id="menu">
        <p>anything can go here</p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#about">About us</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#about/history">History</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#about/team">The team</a>

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#about/team/management">Management</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#about/team/sales">Sales</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#about/team/development">Development</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#about/address">Our address</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

are you using bootstrap? I had the same issue to but I added the class "navbar-fixed-top" into my header and it worked. Note, I also use the add-on FixedTop from mmenu. You can find that info here: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/addons/fixed-elements.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using Skeleton. I will have to look at the css rules for bootstrap's navbar-fixed-top. Thanks for responding. I ended up not fixing the navbar to the top.